# Installing Clisp on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, clisp

Has anyone managed to install CLisp on Windows 8. I am unable to get it to work. I downloaded the exe from SF. But, after I allow the application to run as administrator, I see *nothing*. I did notice that I was unable to delete the file. So, I suspect that there is a prompt that I'm not seeing. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows 8 and Clisp sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: Can you try the zip file instead?

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the laugh. I switched to 8 from Fedora. It is a long sad story that deserves s separate thread.

Comment: @sds I did try to grab the source. But, it was in a GZ format. When I tried to install gzip I had a similar issue. Oddly enough Windows provided me with an error when I tried to install an older version. It plainly stated that it was not going to allow me to download it since it was rarely downloaded. I didn't think to check the Windows store. ;-)

Comment: I did not mean the source. I meant the binary distribution in the zip format.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

I think that I found it. I was able to install it. I suspect that the installation windows being sent to another session. My daughter was signed on while I was working on this (over several days). After a slow reboot (Thank you Microsoft Update), it worked as expected. I would classify this as an I-D-10-T error except that I think it was reasonable for me to see the dialog regardless of whether or not another user was signed in. Thanks again to all of the commenters.